# how to use vue 3 globalProperties templet for filter string?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```
<template>
  <h1>HOOKS</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>userId</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>body</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(data, index) in GetDatas" :key="index">
      <td>{{ data.userId }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.title | snap }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.body }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
  snap(val) {
    if (!val || typeof val !== 'string') return "";
    return val.slice(0, 5);
  }
};

app.mount('#app');
```

here global function in main js for filter my content slice but i get 0 value in that content in `<td>{{ data.title | snap }}</td>` what is the reason for its? im miss any this  here

`if (val === null || val === undefined || typeof val !== 'string')` i useed this too but same result

Comment: `snap` is a function, it expects an argument too ... maybe you want `{{ snap(data.title) }}` - oh, wait `|` used to be in vue2 as a filter "pipe" - see the migration guide for migrating vue2 filters to vue3

Answer (score 0):

@jaromandaX guidelines
it will work in `<td>{{ $filters.snap( data.title) }}</td>`